# How to write a while loop that allocates 500kb of memory via malloc in a while loop

Tags: c, malloc

I am a novice C programmer. I am trying to test the limits of the malloc function by allocating memory 500kb at a time until malloc returns null. I have tried several thing, but nothing is working. Will someone help me fix my code so it does what I would like it to? Also, how should I print out the last memory address? Here is what I currently have:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int tf = 1;
    while(tf==1)
    {
        p=(int*) malloc(500*4);
        if(p == NULL)
        {
            tf = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "but nothing is working." - that's not a question.

Comment: you know 500 is byte right....

Comment: What errors/warnings you got? btw what is `torf` ?

Comment: @Steve: I guess it is 500*4 bytes (assuming `int` is 4 bytes in his system)

Comment: @chouaib It's just `malloc(500)`, no `* sizeof(int)`, so it is 500 bytes.

Comment: Should I alter my call to malloc to be: "malloc(sizeof(int))"? I don't understand that.

Comment: @MitchWheat I added a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int counter = 0;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        p=(int*) malloc(500*1000);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", counter/2);//mem size in MB
    printf("%p\n", p);//address
    return 0;
}
```

try this instead

Comment: will you help me print out the last address, and how much total memory is allocated?

Comment: I am getting a large amount of complier errors.It doesn't recognize: "cout", "end1", or "end"

Comment: @anonymous i tried to fix it up a bit.see if it works. Again, code not tested im just here to show the idea

Comment: @Steve what is     cout ? and what is     endl ? It does not recognize those names/calls/functions.

Comment: beautiful! Except for the address printf statement. I had to replace "%d" with "%p%. Thank you so very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here, based on your description of your approach.

Firstly, that's allocating 500 bytes at a time, not 500 kilobytes.

Secondly, there's no way to break out of the while loop. So, you'll just be spinning there forever, even after malloc starts returning null.

Lastly, that shouldn't even compile, much less run, as torf isn't declared anywhere.

You're on the right track, but I seriously doubt you actually managed to build that.

Comment: I fixed my code. It did compile. However, I ended up with an infinite loop. I will alter the memory issue, and change it to 500kb.

Comment: "I seriously doubt you actually managed to build that" ? :( Jerk. This is my first week learning C.

Comment: Hey, you said you tried it but it didn't work.  Try to understand the difference between "fails to compile" and "doesn't work as expected".  If you're going to be doing this for a while, then explaining where the error happened is important.

Comment: I know the difference between it not compiling and not working as I expected it to. It compiled. It did not do what I expected it to (I had an infinite loop).